# What are black dwarfs?

Tags: white-dwarfs

What are black dwarfs what does they do? Please don't put a comment that I mistook for a black hole I know what a black hole is and also know that there is no relation between them because black hole forms from neutron star but black dwarf from White dwarf OK please give me an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A white dwarf is a compact star where fusion has stopped: it emits light because it starts off very hot.  Over time it will slowly cool down, becoming cooler and therefore redder, until, eventually, it ends up essentially black, at some low temperature.  This final state is a black dwarf.  The time constants involved are very long: I think longer than the current age of the universe, so no black dwarves are expected to exist yet.

(For a long time I thought that white dwarves also generated power by collapsing slowly to some smaller final state, but I think they are already supported by electron degeneracy pressure, so are essentially as small as they can be without some traumatic collapse to a neutron star or beyond.)

As an aside: a search for 'black dwarf' will find a number of very good articles on them.  Probably doing that before asking here would have been a good idea.

Comment: Yea I have searched it the sites almost said the same but I can't understand them please explain in understandable form

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore  A black dwarf is simply a white dwarf that is no longer hot enough on it's surface to be glowing in visible light.   A surface temperature that has cooled to below 2,800 degrees K.   That much cooling takes a long time, so there probably aren't any black dwarfs in the universe yet.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_dwarf